# Modify A Copy of a Structure's Field/Slot in Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I'm trying to modify a copy of a structure's field. I tried using `COPY-TREE` without avail. Here is my code:

```lisp
(defstruct scenario
  (board '() :type list)
  (letters "" :type string)
  (blank-char #\- :type character))

(defparameter *scen-1*
  (make-scenario
    :board (string->board "cat---|a-----|b-----" #\|)))
```

Before `SETF`ing:

```lisp
(print *scen-1*)

#S(SCENARIO
   :BOARD ("CAT---" "A-----" "B-----")
   :LETTERS ""
   :BLANK-CHAR #\-)
```

When I try to modify a copy of the board with `COPY-TREE`, it modifies the original board.

```lisp
(let ((board (copy-tree (scenario-board *scen-1*))))
  (setf (subseq (nth 1 board) 0 2) "GG"))

(print *scen-1*)

#S(SCENARIO
   :BOARD ("CAT---" "GG----" "B-----")
   :LETTERS ""
   :BLANK-CHAR #\-)
```

`*scen-1*` *should* be untouched.

How can I modify a copy of the `BOARD` field, not the original? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `COPY-TREE` copies the list structure, but not the elements of the list. You don't really need `COPY-TREE` here because the list to be copied is flat.

One fix would be to write a function that replaces characters in a copy of a string with characters from another string, and then to replace the desired `board` element in a copy of the original `board`. Here is a function that does the substring replacement:

```
;;; Writes the characters from NEW to OLD starting from START.
(defun replace-substring (old start new)
  (let ((result (copy-seq old)))
    (loop for replacement across new
          for i from start below (+ start (length new))
          do (setf (elt result i) replacement)
          finally (return result))))
```

And here is a function that updates a *copy* of the `board` field by updating a *copy* of one of its string elements:

```
;;; Creates a copy of the BOARD field with the Nth string replaced
;;; by a copy which has had the characters starting from POS
;;; replaced by the characters from NEW.
(defun update-board (board n pos new)
  (let ((new-board (copy-list board))
        (new-seq (replace-substring (nth n board) pos new)))
    (setf (nth n new-board) new-seq)
    new-board))
```

Sample interaction:

```
CL-USER> *scen-1*
#S(SCENARIO :BOARD ("cat---" "a-----" "b-----") :LETTERS "" :BLANK-CHAR #\-)

CL-USER> (update-board (scenario-board *scen-1*) 1 0 "gg")
("cat---" "gg----" "b-----")

CL-USER> *scen-1*
#S(SCENARIO :BOARD ("cat---" "a-----" "b-----") :LETTERS "" :BLANK-CHAR #\-)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the above answer, I found that `MAPCAR` and `COPY-SEQ` can be used to perform a "deep copy" of a list of strings.

```lisp
(let ((board (mapcar #'copy-seq (scenario-board *scen-1*))))
etc
```

This does the trick as well.

Comment: Probably `alexandria:copy-sequence` too ("missing" functions are often in Alexandria).